# How to add custom property/metadata to PDF 2.0 file

Tags: c#, pdf, metadata, customproperty

I am trying to add custom property/metadata to PDF 2.0 file (like this [customprop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScO0a.png)). I have used PDFSharp, ITextSharp and PDFBox but I couldn't. Is there any free package that can fix the problem.

[link for sample pdf 2.0](https://demo.elibsystem.ru/node/29764)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried SpirePDF? There is a free Nuget that you can try, it worked fine for me with that snippet:

```
using Spire.Pdf;

namespace App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            doc.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\output.pdf");
            doc.DocumentInformation.SetCustomProperty("Name", "Test");
            doc.DocumentInformation.SetCustomProperty("Company", "StackOverflow");
            doc.SaveToFile(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\result.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @osfresia, yes I tried but Spire.PDF Free version is limited to 10 pages of PDF.

Comment: @sergenbag01 try to split the pdf into groups of 10 pages and latter unify them, if you can't find a complete version for free.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom metadata using [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) like that:

```
// NOTE: 
// When used in trial mode, the library imposes some restrictions.
// Please visit http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/trial-restrictions.aspx for more information.
BitMiracle.Docotic.LicenseManager.AddLicenseData("temporary or permanent license key here");

using (var pdf = new PdfDocument("Simple_pdf_2.0_file.pdf"))
{
    pdf.Metadata.Custom.Properties.Add("CustomKey", "CustomValue");

    pdf.Save("SetCustomXmpProperties.pdf");
}
```

Here is the more comprehensive sample: https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Metadata/SetCustomXmpProperties

Disclaimer: I am the co-author of Docotic.Pdf library.